# For Windows - Media player software that can run at a different resolution than windows

Tags: windows, media-player

I have a laptop connected to a 4k tv. Sometimes I'll just use the tv as a laptop screen, in those instances I want the laptop to be 1080p without HDR. But when I want to play a video file, I want to be able to go fullscreen at which point the media player software goes into 4k+HDR mode. When I close the media player, it goes back to ordinary 1080p mode. Is there such a software?

Alternatively, perhaps I can use a macro to quickly switch between resolutions and hdr?